# Overwrote partition table (disk label) on LVM on HW RAID1

Tags: partitioning, raid, lvm

I have made a terrible mistake. I inadvertently updated the disk label on an LVM partition residing on a HW RAID1. I inherited a system that has two 1TB disks in a RAID1. It is/was running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server. The filesystems were set up with LVM. I was trying to add an external 10TB USB disk for local backups but I wrote a GPT disk label to the system disk instead of the USB disk. I recall that the original config had partitions of types ext3 and lvm. I don't think I have done anything else that has modified the disks since updating the disk label.

I have booted the machine with an Ubuntu Desktop DVD in "try Ubuntu" mode. I see /dev/sda but not a second disk. I am making a 'dd' img of /dev/sda for safe keeping.

Is there anything I can do to recover the original partition table and recover my system disk?

I have just been informed by my IT staff that they mistakenly dropped my server from their backups and do not have any saved backups.

Comment: Of course, rescuing the files on the file system is priority one. I can always build a new system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recover my files. Here is a detailed description of
how I used testdisk on my disk image to help get me there.

[Link to cgsecurity.org thread on my problem and how I solved it.](https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10819)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am glad that you were able to solve the problem and you posted an answer and accepted that answer as correct. Please note that a link only answer is not considered sufficient in this site. Please list the steps you took in your answer and use the link as reference.  See [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for the site guidance on this topic.